# Scale versus Precision

Tags: education

I've been trying to work out the difference between **scale** and **precision** in relation to decimal numbers.

**Google**

> Precision is the number of digits in a number. Scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point in a number. For example, the number 123.45 has a precision of 5 and a scale of 2.

Most of the articles seem to be related to SQL data types, as per the following image:

[image]

**Questions**

- Does the same hold true in a purely mathematical context?
- If the above question is true, given the value `0.001`, is its scale `3` and precision `4`?

---

### Edit (for Bounty)

Based on feedback in the comments I've received so far, it seems that "no, scale and precision aren't the terms used to define these numbers", so perhaps a more appropriate question is:

**What are the equivalent terms in mathematics?**

Comment: I have never heard the words "scale" used to describe the numbers after the decimal point before. As far as I know, the words "significant figures" are used, rather than "precision", in science and computing. In floating point numbers in computing the terminology seen at this web site https://float.exposed/ are the usual ones.

Comment: "scale" is for changes of size when drawing bluprints, given as a ratio, a better suit for the concept you are presenting is the "order of magnitude".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Google**
>
> > Precision is the number of digits in a number.

> > [image]

> given the value `0.001`, is its scale `3` and precision `4`?

I've never heard of the word ‘scale’ used in this context. According to the definition in the above image, `0.001` and `7000` have ‘precision’ $1,$ `0.0100` has ‘precision’ $3,$ and `700.0400` has ‘precision’ $7.$

- In statistics, business and science, typically, **precision** = consistency = low variability = closeness of the data points = reproducibility & repeatability.

  In this case, precision and accuracy are orthogonal concepts, and **imprecision is not thought to lead to inaccuracy**.

  Here, we are discussing ‘precision’ with reference to a set of repeated measurements.
- In physics and [numerical analysis](https://academic.oup.com/nsr/article/7/12/1795/6017311), however, I think of **precision** not as a measure of data dispersion, but as a measure of the resolution of the instrument or the recordings or the calculations.

  In this sense, **imprecision** is about uncertainty more than about inconsistency, and **can lead to inaccuracy** (loss of correctness), due to the approximation (rounding and truncation) errors being cumulatively propagated by an algorithm, its numerical instability, or a problem's ill condition.

  Here, we are discussing ‘precision’ with reference to a single or set of non-repeated measurement(s).

[This comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/657598/what-is-meant-by-precision#comment1474589_657605) nicely links these two aspects/interpretations of ‘precision’: “The closer the repeated results are to each other, the more confident you can be about expressing the result with a greater number of digits.”

Comment: Why in your examples does `0.001` and `7000` have precision = 1 (rather than 4), and why does `0.0100` have precision = 3 (rather than 5)?

Comment: Because the image says "number of [*significant* figures](https://miro.medium.com/max/960/0*nVV1hjlffviPeBN2.png)". BTW this is not my definition nor do I follow it.

Comment: So are zeros not considered "significant"?

Comment: It depends. Just google up "significant figures". -)